# Rails manipulate sql data to return unique column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RoR app that does a join between multiple tables and returns the resultset as json back to the client.
I need help in figuring out how to send unique column values only.
For e.g., if you have an employee and department table, doing a join on the two would return:

```
Physics   John   
Physics   Joe
Math      Charlie
Math      Sheila
```

How can I return data back to the client that removes duplicate values, for e.g.

```
Physics => { John, Joe }
Math = > { charlie, Sheila }
```

I want to reduce unnecessary sending of duplicate data over the wire.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Changed it to this (found it on stack overflow) and it worked:

```
@lec_hash = @lectures.inject({}) do | result, row |
    result[row.subject] = [] if result[row.subject].nil?
    result[row.subject] << row.name
    result
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare a hash where key is your subject name and value is array of names opted the subject

```
hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
result.each do |row|
  hash[ row.subject]  << row.name
end
```

**Assumptions** :  `result` is array of AR records and model has `subject` and `name`(person's name) attribute(column)

and then convert `hash.to_json`

Comment: Thanks Amit. I tried this, and I get a TypeError(can't convert String into Integer).

Comment: which line is causing error? Are you sure result is the result of your query and the models in the resultant array has subject and name as column name?

Comment: though its not subject and name, they are varchar fields..TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):
  app/controllers/experiments_controller.rb:30:in `[]'
  app/controllers/experiments_controller.rb:30:in `block in get_experiment_data'
  app/controllers/experiments_controller.rb:29:in `each'
  app/controllers/experiments_controller.rb:29:in `get_experiment_data'

Comment: This will little help. Just edit your question and include snippets of  your controller and models

Comment: Thanks Amit. Got the idea from your code. So marking it as solved.